# Derivative of function inside absolute value INSIDE square root

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f'(x)\,=\,\sqrt{\left|x-1\right|}$$

I'm not sure how to go about solving this. I know from online calculators what the answer will end up being, but I don't know how to deal with the square root AND the absolute value signs simultaneously.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably you meant that $f(x)$ is that expression, and you want to find $f'(x)$?

Comment: Please click "Edit" above to fix, if that's not quite what you meant.

Comment: This looks like a job for the chain rule.

Comment: In general, the derivative of $g(|x-1|)=g(\sqrt{(x-1)^2}$ is $$g'\left(\sqrt{(x-1)^2}\right)\frac{2(x-1)}{2\sqrt{(x-1)^2}}=g'(|x-1|)\frac{x-1}{|x-1|}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is what the user "311411" stated.

**Hints:**

- Recall that the square root can be written as $\sqrt{|x-1|} = |x-1|^{1/2}$.
- Note that for $x\geq 1$ it is $|x-1| = x-1$ whereas for $x<1$ it is $|x-1| = -x+1$.

Can you take it on from here?

Comment: Thank you very much! what I'm still a bit confused about though, is that at this point I get to 1/(x-1)^1/2 and 1/(-x+1)^1/2. I'm pretty new to derivatives, but I'm not sure how to reconcile these two independent derivatives? Is there a way to, or would I just leave it as a sort of piece-wise derivative? (if that exists?)

Comment: @duderoni Of course it will be piece-wise since it involves an absolute value. But check again your calculations, they are mistaken. Apply the basic rules you've been taught in terms or differentiation. Don't forget to upvote any answer or comment that is useful to you, it helps the community. Also, since I see you're a new member, welcome wholeheartedly!